# if there is an end for the command `dir(' '.__dir__.__dir__.__dir__.__dir__)` to stop printing its attributes?

Tags: python, python-internals

Every object has a `__dir__` attribute, will the command stop if extra `.__dir__` references are appended?

```
>>> dir(''.__dir__)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__']
```

and,

```
>>> dir(''.__dir__.__dir__.__dir__.__dir__)
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__']
```

will it stop when enough '.**dir**' are appended?

Comment: Well, if you use a heck of a lot of calls to `__dir__`, you'll eventually clutter the memory, and the execution'll possibly stop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are taking the `dir()` of the `__dir__` attribute, which is a `builtin_function_or_method` object, which has a `__dir__` attribute. So yes, you can chain those `__dir__` attribute lookups endlessly, because the result will always be the same; a bound method object:

```
>>> ''.__dir__.__dir__
<built-in method __dir__ of builtin_function_or_method object at 0x10672cfc0>
>>> ''.__dir__.__dir__.__dir__
<built-in method __dir__ of builtin_function_or_method object at 0x1067361f8>
```

*Every* object in Python has a [`__dir__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__), it is always a callable.

Note: the way you strung the attribute lookups keeps a chain of bound method objects alive, so you will eventually run out of memory; each `__dir__` method wrapper references the preceding one in their `__self__` attribute.

Comment: suffix to repeat any  '__someAttribute__'  is  endless call its returned value's attributes.

Comment: May an object not have a `__dir__`? From the docs: "If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be called", so it seems to be optional.

Comment: @VPfB: `type` and `object` both implement `__dir__`, so in Python 3, **all** objects have that method. Only Python 2 old-style classes lack the attribute.